# How to create a custom distribution strategy on Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-tensorflow

I', looking to write a custom distribution strategy for tensorflow.

Currently there are several types strategies available (MirroredStrategy,   TPUStrategy, ...), but i would like to implement a new way of distributing training across several machines.

I looked through the documentation and didn't find any tutorial or guide on how to implement a custom strategy

Is there already a predefined way to do this?

Comment: have you solved this problem and by how because I'm also preparing to implement the model parallelism strategy on Tensorflow.

Comment: I didn't manage to implement a new strategy. I implemented my distribution strategy outside the tensorflow enviroment. It is not ideal but it workerd.